# How to apply Java patches?

Tags: java, patch

Basically, I'm looking to find out how to apply Java patch files using Java. So, to sum that up, I need Java code to apply a patch file to a java source file.
Cheers!

Comment: Are you trying to apply a diff to a java source file, or patching a compiled program by adding the patch to the classpath?

Comment: Patching a compiled program by adding the patch to the classpath, however, I am curious on how to apply a diff to a java source file, so I would appreciate if you explained both to me. Thanks!

Comment: To add a patch to a compiled program, you put the patch first in the classpath, this will override any existing classes. To apply a patch using diff, I suggest you read the manual for diff (or get your IDE to do it, which is what I do now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to extend functionality of the already developed Java application.

You can for example use external non-runnable `*.jar` files with some extra classes. To do so, you have to first implement proper "uploading" functions in your app, e.g. by using custom `ClassPath` objects, which is nicely described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964598/how-to-call-a-class-from-non-runnable-jar-in-java-program), or you can try to use multi `URLClassLoader`s, which is described [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-classloader-handling).

There is also another approach, which allows you to call external methods in form of a `String`, but I haven't tested it yet, altough you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994802/java-transform-string-into-code).